# c code for web pages in rl-rtx

Tags: c, cgi, webserver

we have to work with RL-RTX (RTOS) in our project.in that we have to do some web pages.we have experience in building web pages in linux using "go-ahead webserver".

can we code in c language and store that executable in .cgi extension and call from the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Almost all web servers can be configured to serve cgi. You could use something like [libcgi](http://libcgi.sourceforge.net/) to handle the interface in your c code. Still, it would probably be more efficient to use some kind of scripting language rather than c.